# DateTime Format Issue in c# for multiple Application on same IIS server

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iis

I deployed my ASP.Net web application and WCF web service to the same default web site on the same IIS server with the same application pool. When I use the web application I see the `DateTime.UtcNow` value in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. When I use the WCF web service I see the `DateTime.UtcNow` value in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

How can I make the two agree on the same format? Ideally it should get the local machine time format, which is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Is there any kind of settings is provided in the web.config file or machine config file or IIS settings so that all the application are able to fetch the correct date time format?

My WCF soap services uses the soapUi tool.

Below are the observed DateTime formats for each application:

```
main App: dd/mm/yyyy
wcf webservices: mm/dd/yyyy
local machine : mm/dd/yyyy
applicationPool:  asp.net4.5
```

Comment: Why does this matter? Where is it causing a problem? I ask because, if you're using actual `DateTime` values, **there is no format**. It's a binary (not human-readable) value. You only see a format as a convenience in the bugger or when converting to a string. Of course, the SOAP calls are using a string value over the wire, but that's different from what either the wcf service or the asp.net application are doing internally.

Comment: `My WCF soap services uses the soapUi tool` <= When serializing / deserializing `DateTime` values you should always ensure the library responsible for this is doing it using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Other than that, like Joel Coehoorn already mentioned, you should always be using `DateTime` instances which do not have a format. This also holds true when working with persistence layers many of which also allow for a Date or DateTime type.